# Finding Basin Length tool in Arc Hydro

Tags: arcmap, arc-hydro, arcgis-10.8, basin

I am following [this](http://downloads.esri.com/archydro/archydro/tutorial/doc/arc%20hydro%20tools%202.0%20-%20tutorial.pdf) tutorial on Arc Hydro and I couldn't find the `Basin Length` function in my `Arc toolbox`. On page 84, the tutorial says:

> Select Watershed Processing | Basin Length.

However, I couldn't find `Basin Length` function in my `Watershed Processing` tools. The following figure shows what I have.

[image]

Why can't I see the `Basin tool` function?

I am using ModelBuilder in ArcGIS-10.8 with Arc Hydro 10.8, so I also need to have the function listed in my `ArcToolbox` so that I can drag and drop it in the ModelBuilder window.

**Update**

Based on the comments below, I checked the `line processing toolsets`, but I couldn't find the `Basin tools` in there (see the picture below). Is it possible that the basin length function has been removed from Arc Hydro in the version I am using? The reason why I am thinking that the function may have been removed is that the tutorial I mentioned was made with Arc Hydro 2.0. But I couldn't find the version 2.0 for download. [Here](https://downloads.esri.com/archydro/archydro/Setup) are the versions I have access to.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried expanding the Line Processing toolset?  In your picture it’s collapsed so maybe the “missing” tool is there.

Comment: I updated the question based on your comment. Is it possible that the basin length function has been removed from Arc Hydro in the version I am using?

Comment: What version of Arc Hydro are you using?  I don’t use it myself but that detail may help a potential answerer to help you.

Comment: I am using Arc Hydro 10.8. The reason why I am thinking that the function may have been removed is that the tutorial I mentioned was made with Arc Hydro 2.0. But I couldn't find the version 2.0 for download. See the version I have access to at http://downloads.esri.com/archydro/archydro/Setup/

Comment: Those would be important details to [edit] into your question.